# Detect changes in directory

Tags: c#, scripting, filesystems, directory, monitor

I need to monitor a folder and its subdirectories for any file manipulations (add/remove/rename). I've read about FileSystemWatcher but I'd like to monitor changes between each time the program is run or when the user presses the "check for changes" button (FSW seems more orientated to runtime detection). My first thought was to iterate through all the (sub)directories and hash each file. Then, concatenate all the hashes (which have been ordered) and hash that. When I want to check for changes, I repeat the process and check if the hashes are the same.

Is this an efficient way of doing it?
Also, once I've detected a change, how do I find out what file has been added, removed or renamed as quickly as possible?

As a side note, I don't mind using scripts to do this if they're faster as long as those scripts don't require end users to install anything and the scripts can notify my C# app of the changes.

Comment: I'm confused about what you are looking to do and exactly what FileSystemWatchner doesn't do that you need it to do.

Comment: AFAIK, FSW won't detect file changes between the time the program is shutdown and turned back on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We handle this by storing all found files in a database along with their last modification time.

On each pass through the files, we check the database for each file: if it doesn't exist in the DB, it is new and if it does exist, but the timestamp is different, it has changed.

There is also an option to handle deleted files by marking all of the files in the database as ToBeDeleteed prior to the pass and clearing this if the file was found. Then, at the end of the process, we can just delete all of the records that are marked as ToBeDeleted.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you need to make "snapshots" of the directory tree and compare them as required. What exactly goes into the snapshots would depend on your requirements. Keep in mind that:

- You need to store filenames in order to detect "new" and "deleted" files
- File sizes and last-modified times are a good and cheap indicator that a file has or has not changed, but do not provide a guarantee
- Hashing the contents of files can be prohibitively expensive if the files can be large, but it's the only way to know they have changed with a near-perfect degree of accuracy (remember that hashes can collide as well, so if you want mathematical 100% certainty that's not going to be good enough either)